# Manipulating columns in pandas, Dataframe or Series

Tags: python, pandas, gps, dataframe, series

I'm trying to plot RINEX (GPS) data and am very new to Pandas, numpy. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
#Plotting of the data
pr1  = sat['P1']
pr2  = sat['P2']
calc_pr = pr1 - (((COEFF_3)**2) * pr2)
plt.plot(calc_pr,label='calc_pr')
```

where "sat" is a Dataframe as follows:

```
sat:
Panel: <class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 32 (items) x 2880 (major_axis) x 7 (minor_axis)
Items axis: G01 to G32
Major_axis axis: 0.0 to 23.9916666667
Minor_axis axis: L1 to S2
```

where each Item (G01, G02, etc) corresponds to:

```
(G01)
DataFrame:                     L1           L2            P1            P2            C1  \
0.000000    669486.833   530073.330  24568752.516  24568762.572  24568751.442   
0.008333    786184.519   621006.551  24590960.634  24590970.218  24590958.374   
0.016667    902916.181   711966.252  24613174.234  24613180.219  24613173.065   
0.025000   1019689.006   802958.016  24635396.428  24635402.410  24635395.627
```

Within the first column (I assume this is the major axis, which I manipulated with: epoch_time = int((hour * 3600) + (minute * 60) + second)), states the time. These are 30 second intervals, over 24h. They were originally epochs (0 to 2880). The first epochs "calc_pr" are shown below:

```
Series: 0.000000     26529.507524
0.008333     31432.322196
0.016667     36336.563310
0.025000     41242.536096
0.033333     46149.208022
0.041667     51057.059006
0.050000     55965.873639
0.058333     60875.510720
0.066667     65785.965112
0.075000     70697.114838
```

However when plotting these (plt.plot(calc_pr,label='calc_pr')) instead of the x-axis being the time in hours, it is displayed in epochs. I've tried different permutations of trying to manipulate this
"calc_pr" so that the times are displayed, not epoch numbers, but so far to no avail. Could someone indicate where/how I can manipulate this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I solved this myself in the end. I realised I just need to plot the "index", like so:

```
plt.plot(sat.index, calc_pr, label='calc_pr')
```

I love it when I solve my own problems myself. It means I'm getting even more awesome.